# changing directory of asp.net membership tables in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-membership, connection-string

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2012.
using web forms, by default the app is created with an account folder. Inside this account folder there is 4 .aspx pages, a .ascx file and a blank web.config file.

By default in vs2012 the data collected from the registration.aspx page is saved to (localdb)v11.0, but I cannot see this db with sql server 2008.

I have a custom DB with the exact asp.net membership tables and would like to use these default aspx pages provided by asp.net/vs2012 with my database.

I have added a ADO.NET Entity Model to my app and have successfully connected to my DB, so I can get a connection.

When I change my app's web.config file connection string to use my DB instead of the 'DefaultConnection', the default Registration page is still saving data to (localdb)v11.0.

(I know its still saving data because I registered as a new user >> logged out >> reset the app >> logged in as the same credentials >> checked my DB and there is no data in my DB)

How would I go about changing the directory of the aspnet membership tables so that they are saved to my database instead of the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose which connection string will be used by membership provider in this section of web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="connStringName" applicationName="applicationName" enablePasswordRetrieval="True" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordFormat="Clear" name="SQLMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```